# Elasticsearch - value in array filter

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, filter

I want to filter out all documents which contain a specific value in an array field. I.e. the value is an element of that array field.

To be specific - I want to select all documents which `names` contains `test-name`, see the example below.

So when I do an empty search with

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test-index/_search
```

the result is

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 50,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "34873ae4-f394-42ec-b2fc-41736e053c69",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "names": [
            "test-name"
          ],
          "age": 100,
          ...
        }
      },
      ...
   }
}
```

But in case of a more specific query

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test-index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}

      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
           "names": "test-name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I don't get any results

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

There are some questions similar to this one. Although, I cannot get any of the answers to work for me.

System specs: `Elasticsearch 5.1.1`, `Ubuntu 16.04`

**EDIT**

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test-index
          ...
          "names": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `names` field is analyzed and `test name` gets indexed as two tokens `test` and `name`.

Searching for the `test name` term  will hence not yield anything. If you use `match` instead, you'll get the document.

If you want to check for the exact value `test name` (i.e. the two tokens one after another), then you need to change your `names` field to a `keyword` type instead of `text`

**UPDATE**

According to your mapping, the `names` field is analyzed, you need to use the `names.keyword` field instead and it will work, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test-index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}

      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
           "names.keyword": "test-name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: `names` is type `keyword`. Changing query to `{ "query": { "match": { "names": "test-name" } } }` returns more than a single result.

Comment: can you update your question with the result you get for running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/test-index` ?

Comment: You've changed the question now from `test name` to `test-name`... hmmmm

Comment: Yes, didn't notice that before, sorry.

Comment: Still my second comment stands.

Comment: `{ "query": { "match": { "names.keyword": "test name" } } }` works as well!

Comment: Yes, because the `names.keyword` field is not analyzed.